# C# NET 5.0 source generator basic example is not generating output

Tags: c#, .net, sourcegenerators

I am copying everything as closely as I can from the [Microsoft website example](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/) but nothing is generating. I created a MCVE to try to find out why the following error happens:

```
Warning CS8034  
Unable to load Analyzer assembly C:\Users\me\source\repos\SourceGenTest\SourceGenerators\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\SourceGenerators.dll: 
Could not find file 'C:\Users\me\source\repos\SourceGenTest\SourceGenerators\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\SourceGenerators.dll'.
SourceGenLibrary        1   Active
```

I have checked the path provided, and `SourceGenerators.dll` exists. The error makes no sense to me.

**Note:** In the MCVE I provided, apparently there's no build warnings. Not sure why, but there's still no output from the source generator.

My goal is to have a workflow like:

```
SourceGenerators (class library)
    is consumed by
        SourceGenLibrary (class library)
            is consumed by
                SourceGenConsole (Console project)
```

Whereby I want an analyzer to generate definitions in a class library that will be shared among many projects. The above workflow reduces it to one project depending on one library which depends on the source generators to keep this as MCVE-as-possible.

Because copying all of this stuff, is annoying, here's an upload link if you're lazy: [Download link MCVE](https://filebin.net/hck9ud6kclvr95rk/SourceGenerators.zip?t=zgwg4b1f) (expires a week after posting supposedly, but the source is below).

Relevant info:

```
$ dotnet --version
5.0.201

$ dotnet --list-sdks
5.0.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

---

These are the source files and what they contain.

**/SourceGenTest.sln**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.31112.23
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "SourceGenLibrary", "SourceGenLibrary\SourceGenLibrary.csproj", "{8702B80A-ACA3-4546-BBE8-A9FEE686A758}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "SourceGenerators", "SourceGenerators\SourceGenerators.csproj", "{D693D3B2-F981-4D6D-AC97-B8C636E8C5C0}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "SourceGenConsole", "SourceGenConsole\SourceGenConsole.csproj", "{3730848C-847C-4DF9-A0B3-5ADB5FE9D1E0}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {8702B80A-ACA3-4546-BBE8-A9FEE686A758}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {8702B80A-ACA3-4546-BBE8-A9FEE686A758}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {8702B80A-ACA3-4546-BBE8-A9FEE686A758}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {8702B80A-ACA3-4546-BBE8-A9FEE686A758}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {D693D3B2-F981-4D6D-AC97-B8C636E8C5C0}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {D693D3B2-F981-4D6D-AC97-B8C636E8C5C0}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {D693D3B2-F981-4D6D-AC97-B8C636E8C5C0}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {D693D3B2-F981-4D6D-AC97-B8C636E8C5C0}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {3730848C-847C-4DF9-A0B3-5ADB5FE9D1E0}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {3730848C-847C-4DF9-A0B3-5ADB5FE9D1E0}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {3730848C-847C-4DF9-A0B3-5ADB5FE9D1E0}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {3730848C-847C-4DF9-A0B3-5ADB5FE9D1E0}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {A3752997-47E1-4086-87C8-1583B5E0EDF1}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

**/SourceGenerators/SourceGenerators.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="3.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**/SourceGenerators/Class1.cs**

```
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;

namespace SourceGeneratorSamples
{
    [Generator]
    public class HelloWorldGenerator : ISourceGenerator
    {
        public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
        {
            // begin creating the source we'll inject into the users compilation
            var sourceBuilder = new StringBuilder(@"
            using System;
            namespace HelloWorldGenerated
            {
                public static class HelloWorld
                {
                    public static void SayHello() 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(""Hello from generated code!"");
                        Console.WriteLine(""The following syntax trees existed in the compilation that created this program:"");
            ");

            // using the context, get a list of syntax trees in the users compilation
            var syntaxTrees = context.Compilation.SyntaxTrees;

            // add the filepath of each tree to the class we're building
            foreach (SyntaxTree tree in syntaxTrees)
            {
                sourceBuilder.AppendLine($@"Console.WriteLine(@"" - {tree.FilePath}"");");
            }

            // finish creating the source to inject
            sourceBuilder.Append(@"
                    }
                }
            }");

            // inject the created source into the users compilation
            context.AddSource("helloWorldGenerator", SourceText.From(sourceBuilder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8));
        }

        public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**/SourceGenLibrary/SourceGenLibrary.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
    <AssemblyName>SourceGenLibrary</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SourceGenerators\SourceGenerators.csproj" OutputItemType="Analyzer" ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**/SourceGenLibrary/Class1.cs**

```
using System;

namespace SourceGenTest
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Func()
        {
            //HelloWorldGenerator.HelloWorld.SayHello();
        }
    }
}
```

**/SourceGenConsole/SourceGenConsole.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SourceGenLibrary\SourceGenLibrary.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**/SourceGenConsole/Program.cs**

```
using System;

namespace SourceGenConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to clone complete project from [roslyn-sdk repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/tree/main/samples/CSharp/SourceGenerators) and then adapt this code to your needs

Comment: @JL0PD I am running into the exact same problem with the example in the sdk repo. I run the stuff (after updating it to the latest nuget packages since it won't compile) and get the `cannot find SourceGeneratorSamples.dll` error, which causes the analyzer to not run.

Comment: I hit an error loading Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp v3.9.0, but v3.8.0 worked with my version of visual studio.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman That worked for me as well. As of today the current version is 3.11.0, but I had to revert to 3.8.0 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, the previous answer was completely wrong. Also, my rep is too low to comment, so I'm submitting this.

I was trying to do something similar with 3 projects and getting a similar error (although I had many other issues too). I had to add a reference to the source generator in the bottom project (Console in your case). Also I added a `Debugger.Launch()` which helped dive down on specific issues.

Comment: That's okay. Did you find a solution that worked? If you did, can you post the code of the files so I could copy paste them and try it out myself?

Comment: I didn't find a solution that worked actually. I ended up combining my library and source generator into one project, and then adding 2 references to it (one as an analyzer with the `OutputItemType` and `ReferenceOutputAssembly` parameters, and one just referenced regularly.

Comment: @TheNextFreud Your solution of adding 2 references didn't work for me. Reverting to Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 3.8.0 worked, as indicated by JeremyLakeman above. I'm open to suggestions that will allow me to use the current version though!